# Moodle API All users completed courses

Tags: wordpress, moodle, moodle-api

I wanna make a export page for all completed courses from each user. but which API function I can use best.

I have found the function `core_completion_get_course_completion_status`, but the problem is that it needs a `courseid` and a `userid`. The problem is that with 100 users and every user has 20 couses he has to make 100 x 20 = 2000 API calls. I find that a lot myself.

Does anyone have a better way for me?

Comment: You should probably write your own

Comment: @EvgeniyVoevodin Do you have any link for the documentation for making my  own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make a [plugin](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Tutorial#Let.27s_make_a_plugin) first, then populate it with [web service](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services_API)